# LXD Container fails to SSH out to AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, lxc

I have copied over the .ssh keys and config from my main workstation into an LXD container on it. I have also cleared my ip tables which was an issue with docker I believe preventing my bridge from accessing the internet. I do have access now.

Unfortunately the connection times out when I try to SSH out :(

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020                            
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config                                    
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for rabbit-dev                     
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config                                
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no  
files                                                                                 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *                           
debug1: Connecting to ec2-##-###-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com [##.###.###.###] por 
t 22.                                                                                 
debug1: connect to address ##.###.###.### port 22: Connection timed out               
ssh: connect to host ec2-##-###-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection t 
imed out
```

My ~/.ssh/config contains

```
Host rabbit-dev
HostName ec2-##-###-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dev_company.pem
LocalForward 11003 rabbitmq.internal.dev.company.com:80
LocalForward 11004 rabbitmq.internal.dev.company.com:5672
User ec2-user 
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: What are the ingress rules for the security group(s) associated with your EC2 instance?

Comment: And it might help if you clarify your question to indicate whether the EC2 instance is accessible from your main workstation or not.

Comment: @jscott Hi, the ec2 is accessible from the main workstation and the configuration and ssh keys are a copy from the main workstation.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione is it always the same amount of time for the timeout to occur? Also, have you tried specifying explicit values for  `-o ConnectTimeout=<secs>` and/or `-o ServerAliveInterval=<secs>`?

Comment: You know what this turned out to be... docker autoloading puts in iptable firewall rules and blocks the container. I uninstalled docker for now.

Answer (score 1):

Docker prevents host operating as a router which is needed for LXD

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxd-and-docker-firewall-redux-how-to-deal-with-forward-policy-set-to-drop/9953/3